# how to curl uploadrocket in PHP

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

i'm trying to curl the result of `http://uploadrocket.net/?op=checkfiles` and get the filesize result using curl.

i have tried the following:

```
function curl($url,$cookies,$post,$header=1) {
    $ch = @curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    if ($cookies) curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,$url); 
    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    $page = curl_exec( $ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $page;
}

$link = "http://uploadrocket.net/rlajq9dwrxey.htm";

$page = curl('http://uploadrocket.net/?op=checkfiles',"",'list='.urlencode($link).'&process=Check%20URLs');

echo $page;
```

but it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: May not be your issue, but you also require `&op=checkfiles` in your POST string

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ, thanks a lot, i already fixed the problem using file_get_contents instead of curl.
thanks again

Comment: Great - you might as well close this if it is not relevant anymore

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ, you mean delete it since i cannot find close ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$page = file_get_contents('http://uploadrocket.net/?op=checkfiles/links='.$link.'&process=Check%20URLs');

Answer (score 0):

you can't copy it to your HD and make a filesize ? And then delete it if you don't want it (or copy to a  temp dir) ?

Comment: it will use too much bandwidth as it will not be only 1 file :)